# CSS Grid: content goes in the wrong row

Tags: css, grid

I'm learning css grid, and trying to make header with grid areas.

I have logo, menu, title and buttons. I'm trying to make 3x2 grid to position it. it suppose to look like that:

logo-------menu

------text------

The problem is that text area goes in the first row (between logo and menu), when I expect it to appear in the second row.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBSWJ.png)

What do I do wrong?

Here is my html and css:

```
  <div class="header__menu container">
    <a class="logo__link" href="www.moldex3d.com">Moldex3D</a>
    <nav class="menu"> 
      <a class="menu__link" href="#">Промо</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="header__text">
      <h1 class="header__title">Первый среди лучших</h1>
      <h2 class="header__subtitle">Компьютерное моделирование литья пластмасс</h2>
      <a class="button" href="">Попробовать бесплатно!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



.header__menu{
  display: grid;
  
  .logo__link{
    grid-area: logo;
  }
  .menu{
    grid-area: nav;
  }
  &__text{
    grid-area: text;
  }
  
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 8fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 10fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo . nav" ". text .";
  min-height: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found where the problem was.

I put the wrong class for the text block.

&__text refers to .header__menu__text, when it should be just .header__text

Thank you all!